# Forcing BufRead trait compatibility between io::stdio and BufReader

Tags: rust

I'm trying to type-pun an `io::stdio` instance and a `BufReader` wrapping a file so that I can write code assuming a buffered input source. I've tried several variations of trying to cast an `io::stdio()` to a `BufRead` type and all have failed with one or more variations of:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `std::io::stdio::StdinLock<'_>`,
    found `std::io::buffered::BufReader<std::fs::File>`
(expected struct `std::io::stdio::StdinLock`,
    found struct `std::io::buffered::BufReader`) [E0308]
csv_to_json.rs:26     reader = BufReader::new(file.unwrap());
```

Here's the code:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::env;
use std::process::exit;
use std::fs::File;

fn usage() {
    println!("Usage: cat input.csv | csv_to_json");
}

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut reader = stdin.lock();   // Assignment. (1)
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    if args.len() > 1 {
        usage();
        exit(1);
    } else if args.len() == 1 {
        let file = File::open(args[0].clone());
        if !file.is_ok() {
            usage();
            exit(1);
        }
        reader = BufReader::new(file.unwrap());  // Reassignment. This is the line that fails.
    }

    // Rest of the code works with reader assuming a buffered input source.
}
```

Things that I have tried:

```
let mut reader : BufRead = io::stdin();  // Fails.
let mut reader : BufReader<Read> = io::stdin();  // Fails.
let mut reader : BufReader<_> = io::stdin(); // Fails
let mut reader : BufRead = io::stdin().lock(); // Fails later.
let mut reader = BufReader::new(io::stdin());  // Fails with type mismatch.
let mut reader = BufReader::new(io::stdin().lock());  // Fails with type mismatch.
```

I've even tried extracting that code to its own function and the return type signature fails with similar error conditions. How can I create a "reader" variable that's either a `BufferedReader` over `stdio` or a `BufferedReader` over a `File` without facing type errors everywhere?

Comment: The summary of the answers below: Use a "Box" type. A Box is a soft polymorphic reference (similar to a pointer in C / C++ style languages).

Comment: [How to do polymorphic IO from either a File or stdin in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088116)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work.

```
use std::io;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::env;
use std::process::exit;
use std::fs::File;

fn usage() {
    println!("Usage: cat input.csv | csv_to_json");
}

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut reader = Box::new(stdin.lock()) as Box<BufRead>;
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    if args.len() > 1 {
        usage();
        exit(1);
    } else if args.len() == 1 {
        let file = File::open(args[0].clone());
        if !file.is_ok() {
            usage();
            exit(1);
        }
        reader = Box::new(BufReader::new(file.unwrap()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the correct use of Box in such a scenario. Very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Your code can be rewritten so that there is no need to reassign `reader` variable (see @Vladimir Matveev [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36106782/5138648)).

If you really need it, then `reader` variable must be a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html#dynamic-dispatch):

```
let mut bufread;//must be defined before reader to avoid lifetime issues 
let stdin = io::stdin();
let mut reader = &mut stdin.lock() as &mut BufRead;   // Assignment. (1)

//...

bufread = BufReader::new(file.unwrap());//store BufReader value  
reader = &mut bufread;// reassign BufRead reference
```

Boxed form of trait object allows to avoid additional variable `bufread`:

```
let stdin = io::stdin();
let mut reader = Box::new(stdin.lock()) as Box<BufRead>;   

//...

reader = Box::new(BufReader::new(file.unwrap()));
```

Comment: An `&BufRead` won't be very helpful though, since all the interesting `BufRead` methods take `&mut self`.

Comment: I'd like to note that there is no need to declare any of the variables before the condition because they are not used in it. So it is better to rewrite the code to avoid trait objects as they are really unnecessary here.