# Rust generic local variable

Tags: generics, rust, traits

From the book "Rust in Action" (Manning, currently MEAP), the final example of Chapter 2 shows a way to implement a generic function that can work on `BufRead + Sized` parameters:

```rust
fn process_lines<T: BufRead + Sized>(reader: T, re: Regex) {
  for line_ in reader.lines() {
    let line = line_.unwrap();
    match re.find(&line) {
        Some(_) => println!("{}", line),
        None => (),
    }
  }
}
```

The code that uses it looks like:

```rust
let input = args.value_of("input").unwrap_or("-");
if input == "-" {
  let stdin = io::stdin();
  let reader = stdin.lock();
  process_lines(reader, re);
} else {
  let f = File::open(input).unwrap();
  let reader = BufReader::new(f);
  process_lines(reader, re);
}
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to declare the `reader` variable earlier with a generic type so the process_lines() call can be factored out?

```rust
let reader: ????;
let input = args.value_of("input").unwrap_or("-");
if input == "-" {
  let stdin = io::stdin();
  reader = stdin.lock();
} else {
  let f = File::open(input).unwrap();
  reader = BufReader::new(f);
}
process_lines(reader, re);
```

Or by using an (anonymous) method that would return `impl BufRead + Sized` ?

Something like:

```rust
fn build_reader(input: &str) -> impl BufRead + Sized {
  if input == "-" {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    stdin.lock()  
  } else {
    let f = File::open(input).unwrap();
    BufReader::new(f)
  }
}
```

But compiler is not very happy, see https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0e74d3e96de0bbf61b9f61d44d305e5e

**Edit**

I succeeded building a BufRead builder using the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49964042/258622

```rust
fn build_reader(input: &str) -> Box<dyn BufRead> {
  if input == "-" { 
    Box::new(BufReader::new(io::stdin()))
  } else {
    let f = File::open(input).unwrap();
    Box::new(BufReader::new(f))
  }
}
```

Compiler is happy, I wonder what are the consequences of not using `stdin.lock()`...

Main now looks like:

```rust
fn main() {
 ...
 let input = args.value_of("input").unwrap_or("-");
 let reader = build_reader(input);
 process_lines(reader, re)
}
```

Code that compiles: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c5218ef4a266597da6a36c21e060bcda

**Edit 2** : A more idiomatic version taking advantage of the fact that [`clap::ArgMatches::value_of()`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.0/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.value_of) returns an `Option<&str>`:

```rust
fn build_reader(input: Option<&str>) -> Box<dyn BufRead> {
  match input {
    None => Box::new(BufReader::new(io::stdin())),
    Some(filename) => {
      let f = File::open(filename).unwrap();
      Box::new(BufReader::new(f))
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  ...
  let input = args.value_of("input");
  let reader = build_reader(input);
  process_lines(reader, re)
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Also, your solution cannot work because generics and `impl Trait` can only be one type at a time. They can't be chosen at runtime.

Comment: @mcarton for educational purposes

Answer (score 2):

As @sshashank124 has stated, returning `impl SomeTrait` only means the function is to return *one concrete type* that implements `SomeTrait`. It doesn't give the function license to return heterogeneous types.

The fact that [`Stdin::lock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.lock) takes a reference also doesn't help here. It will go out of scope as soon as the function returns or the local scope which it is in ends.

Ignore the issue of `Stdin::lock` for a moment, you can do:

```rust
let stdin = io::stdin();
let reader: Box<dyn BufRead> = if input == "-" {
    Box::new(stdin.lock())
} else {
    let f = File::open(input).unwrap();
    Box::new(BufReader::new(f))
};
process_lines(reader, re);
```

Or with third party crate such as `either`:

```rust
use either::Either;

let stdin = io::stdin();
let reader = if input == "-" {
    Either::Left(stdin.lock())
} else {
    let f = File::open(input).unwrap();
    Either::Right(BufReader::new(f))
};
process_lines(reader, re);
```

It seems trivial in this case. But it may help you in the future.

Comment: Thank you @edwardw, can you also teach me how to deal with Stdin::lock reference ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the method approach (with `impl BufRead`) nor the `if/else` approach will work since the types of the two `BufRead` implementers are different (namely `StdinLock` and `BufReader`). The issue with both of these methods is that they expect a single concrete type. I wouldn't worry too much about trying to factor out something as trivial as this.

In general however, if you wish to have polymorphism at runtime, you can use the `Box<dyn Trait>` pattern to create a trait object. More information on this can be found in the rust book here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html